# Better way to use or condition in js

Tags: javascript

When I write this, my `or` condition works

```
const role = "admin"
if (role === "user" || role === "admin") {

}
```

But why my `or` condition does not work this way

```
if (role === "user" || "admin") {

}
```

If I write this it works

```
if (role === "admin" || "user") {

}
```

I want to make my `if` condition `true` both the times but in second it does not work.

Comment: `||` is an operator, and both your samples are *syntactically* correct but they *mean* significantly different things. It's not clear what your question is however.

Comment: You can always use RegExp.test() `/^(user|admin)$/.test(role)` if you like that syntax more

Comment: `['user', 'admin'].includes(role)`

Comment: @Pointy Sorry I was not clear. I want to make my if condition truthfully both the times but in second it does not work.

Comment: The second way does not work because it doesn't mean what you think it does. It "works" but what it does is different that the first code sample.

Comment: I believe I am not the first who has this doubt. Do you have any duplicate link which can give me an answer? @Pointy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equal-operator has a higher binding as the or-operator, so first is tested `role === "user"`. If this is false because role it is not "user" this will be false. But this doesn't matter because on the other hand `"admin"` is **truethy** and truthy or false is **true**.

Here the 3 cases from the OP:

**1.**

```
const role = "admin";
if (role === "user" || role === "admin") { ... }
```

`role === "user"` is **false**,
`role === "admin"` is **true**
=> `(role === "user" || role === "admin")` is **true**.

**2.**

```
const role = "xxx";
if (role === "user" || "admin") { ... }
```

`role === "user"` is **false**,
`"admin"` is **true**
=> `(role === "user" || "admin")` is **true**.

**3.**

```
 if (role === "user" || "admin") { ... }
```

Error because role is not defined. If you instantiated it with any value you will have case 2.

## Explanation

Here is for better understanding a list of examples for **truethy** in JS (they will be executed):

- if (true)
- if ({})
- if ([])
- if (42)
- if ("foo")
- if (new Date())
- if (-42)
- if (3.14)
- if (-3.14)
- if (Infinity)
- if (-Infinity)

And here is a list of examples for **falsy** in JS (they will NOT executed):

- if (false)
- if (null)
- if (undefined)
- if (0)
- if (0n)
- if (NaN)
- if ('')
- if ("")
- if (``)
- if (document.all)

Comment: Could you pls check the above question and give your answer based on all the three cases

Answer (score -1):

Because that's not how or works. It evaluates the condition on the left for truthiness, then returns with that if it is truthy, otherwise it returns the right side. Any non empty string is truthy, so what you've written is `if (role === /*some truthy value*/ || /*doesn't matter, the first value is truthy*/)` You need to use the first snippet. That's how or is supposed to work.

Alternatively, you could do `if(["user", "admin"].includes(role))`

Comment: "If neither side is truthy, it returns false" — no, that is incorrect. If neither value is truthy, the right-hand value is the result, not `false`.

Comment: Oops. I've been in other programming languages recently. Thanks for the correction.